# codeigniter :load view inside div of a view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

lets say that i hv this view (main)

```
<body>
lorem epsim
<div table></div>
lorem epsim
</body>
```

in controller control1.php i do

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('main',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Now i need to load content of div=table from another view (tbl.php),which is called from another controller

control2.php

```
function load_table(){
$data['x']=1;
$this->load->view('tbl.php',$data);
}
```

tbl.php view

```
<ul>$x</ul>
```

how can i do that ?

i tried to load controler 2 from controller 1 and assign the function load_table to variable and pass that to main view, but it didnt work cuz load->view is executed instead of saving output to variable..

**Reason:**
i need to do this is that tbl.php view is a complex table that i need to refresh and load via ajax calls, so i need it to be on different view alone
so can some one explain to me how can i work this out ?

Comment: Please edit the "text-speak" out of your post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call one controller method from another, separate controller. You can, however, get the output of the table view and use that:

```
// main.php
<body>
lorem epsim
<div table><?php echo $table_content; ?></div>
lorem epsim
</body>
```

.

```
// control1.php

$table_data['x'] = 1;
$data['table_content'] = $this->load->view('tbl.php', $table_data, TRUE);

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('main',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

So, you get the data to pass to the tbl.php view and pass that to the load->view method - also passing `TRUE` as the third parameter - which will return the contents of that view as a string (instead of outputting that to the browser). Now, you have a $data variable to pass to the `main` view with the table html included and you can just echo that out in the main view.

How you get the `$data['table_content']` data from the view is up to you. You can create another controller method **inside** control1.php, you can create a helper file that can load the view into a string and return that, etc.

Comment: in your case, How to get $table_data in view?

Comment: @freestyle - which view?

Comment: As the code is now - you would be able to access the `x` variable in the `tbl.php` file with the `$x` variable.  And then, you would be able to access the `table_content` variable in the `main` view with the `$table_content` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a view with the table code within and then you can do inside your div for ajax

```
<div id="for_ajax">
       <?php $this->load->view('table'); ?>
</div>
```

I've similar needs but mine its like a comments wall for issues.

Comment: if i did that i will not be able to pass variables to tbl view.

Comment: You can do that, I use a template.php, try to load the table view inside the main.php view. The main view recives $data so there wont be problem that table view recives it too.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a view use following in a php block

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->view('view_name');
```