# CodeIngiter: Load a view inside of another view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter. I want to load views inside of other views. How can I do this?

**Example:**

Let's say I have a "view" called "CommentWall". In CommentWall, I want a bunch of "Comment" views. I use the view for "comment" all over my site!

How can I do this? It seems CodeIgniter only allows me to load views sequentially, which is sort of strange considering I use reusable views INSIDE of other views!

Can I do a `$this->load->view('comment');` inside of my view for CommentWall? Or is there some other way to have **reusuable** views contained **inside** a view?

Comment: You can do this, what is the problem you're having?

Comment: It is better to do these things in controllers, may this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317115/is-it-ok-to-put-conditional-logic-on-codeigniter-views/17317621#17317621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily, just load the main view, for example `CommentWall` from the controller

```
$this->load->view('CommentWall');
```

To add child views in `CommentWall` view you can add following line inside your `CommentWall` view

```
$this->view('Comment');
```

For example, if you load `CommentWall` view from your controller like this

```
$data['comments'][] = 'Comment one';
$data['comments'][] = 'Comment two';

// load the parrent view
$this->load->view('CommentWall', $data);
```

Now in the `CommentWall` (parent view), if you put this

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $this->view('Comment', array('comment' => $comment));
}
```

And in your `Comment` (child view) if you have this

```
echo $comment . '<br />';
```

Then you should get output something like this

```
Comment one

Comment two
```

**Update :** Alos, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056347/codeigniter-load-view-inside-div-of-a-view).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $data->comments =$this->load->view('comment');
            $this->load->vars($data);
    }
```

And in every view try

```
echo $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load the "Comment" vies as string in controller and pass it to "CommentWall" view.

You can do it like this:

```
//Controller:

public function load_comment_wall($param) {

       $comments_view = ""; //String that holds comment views

      //here load the comments for this wall as follows:
      //assuming $comment_ids is array of id's of comment to be put in this wall...
      foreach($comment_ids as $comment_id) {
          $temp = $this->load->view("comment",array('comment_id'=>$comment_id),TRUE);     //Setting last parameter to TRUE will returns the view as String
          $comments_view = $comment_views.$temp;
      }

      $data['comments'] = $comments_view;

      //load comment wall
      $this->load->view('comment_wall',$data);
}
```

//In Comment wall View, add the following line

```
echo $comments;
```