# Message: Undefined variable: content_view

Tags: codeigniter

The variable passed in the controller not working in the view.

In my controller I have:

```
 public function index() 
 {   
     $login_data['content_view'] = 'login/login';       
     //echo $login_data['content_view']; die(); //display: login/login
     $this->load->module("template");
     $this->template->login_template($login_data);
  }
```

And in my view :

```
    $this->load->view('partial/header');
    $this->load->view($content_view); // not working
    //$this->load->view('login/login'); // working 
    $this->load->view('partial/footer');
```

I get the following error message:
Message: Undefined variable: content_view

Comment: Your view doesn't know about the controller! you need to read this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: Could you show what the `login_template` method do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you load views (inside a view)!

Views are loaded inside a controller, which supports loading multiple views as well.

Example: You load the static header and common templates, then you load your specific content and then maybe a common footer as below:

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('menu');
            $this->load->view('content', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

That's how the MVC architecture works. Also, the Codeigniter documentation is well written, see: [Views - Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views)

Comment: you can very well load a view from inside a view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17812513/2275490

Comment: Thanks too much for your answer. I forgot tell that I'm using HMVC modular extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I'm using HMVC modular extension for the first time and I forgot to add the variable $data in template.php controller like this:

```
 public function login_template($data=Null) 
 {
    $this->load->view("template/login_template", $data);
 }
```

Before I used:

```
   public function login_template($data=Null) 
   {
      $this->load->view("template/login_template");
   }
```

So thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $data = array();
 $this->template->login_template($login_data);
 $data['content_view'] = 'login/login';
 $this->load->view('header', $data);
```

Comment: Thansk too much! I forgot to add $data variable.